# Safety of using Git's filter-branch to rewrite if only modifications are to commits which haven't been pushed yet?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'd cloned a repo and went along doing local commits before I noticed that I wasn't using the right email address or user name.  Using this script here, I successfully ran the filter-branch and got the results I was looking for:

https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info

My theoretical understanding from posts here is that I can affect anything that hasn't been pushed, and not cause trouble for other people.  That should be true, I think, even if I've been merging other people's commits from the master.  But I'd like to make sure that theory lines up with practice in this very specific case!

Restated: *If the only email address and user name records that were modified are the ones with my name that have never been pushed, is this safe?*  And am I correct in believing that it suddenly becomes unsafe if (for instance) I tried changing the email names in a commit which exists in the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a `git filter-branch`, you can see the original commits in `.git/refs/original`.
See "[how to remove old commits after `filter-branch`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223053/how-to-remove-old-commits-after-filter-branch?rq=1)" for more on that directory.

If none of those SHA1 were present in a remote repo, you are safe, and can push the modified repo whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As long as you're only affecting commits that no one else has seen yet, you're fine.

Comment: Good news.  I wonder, is there any way to know which commits were affected?  It didn't really give any feedback on that...the output of the operation just ran through the hundreds of patches and left the terminal with a single line of output saying `Rewrite [hash] ([num]/[num])`.  So I'm just taking it on faith that it didn't touch anything I didn't want it to.  :-/